# shopping cart total price issue

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I am working on a shopping cart project for my college project in final page of my cart i want to calculate the total amount for the all the product in the cart help me in that code for that is
for cart.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
              runat="server" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              DataKeyNames="id" 
              DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
              EmptyDataText="No Item in the Cart">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="pName" 
                            HeaderText="pName" 
                            SortExpression="pName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="brand" 
                            HeaderText="brand" 
                            SortExpression="brand" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="img" 
                               SortExpression="img">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" 
                                 runat="server" 
                                 Text='<%# Bind("img") %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" 
                               runat="server" 
                               ImageUrl='<%# Bind("img") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="quantity" 
                            HeaderText="quantity" 
                            SortExpression="quantity" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="price" 
                            HeaderText="price" 
                            SortExpression="price" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
                       runat="server" 
                       ConnectionString="<%                              $ConnectionStrings:shopingConnectionString1 %>" 
                       DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [completeCart] WHERE [id] = @id"
                       InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [completeCart] ([uName], [pName], [brand], [img], [quantity], [price]) VALUES (@uName, @pName, @brand, @img, @quantity, @price)"
                       SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [completeCart] WHERE ([uName] = @uName)" 
                       UpdateCommand="UPDATE [completeCart] SET [uName] = @uName, [pName] = @pName, [brand] = @brand, [img] = @img, [quantity] = @quantity, [price] = @price WHERE [id] = @id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int64" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="uName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="pName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="brand" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="img" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="quantity" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="price" Type="Int64" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:CookieParameter CookieName="uname" 
                                 Name="uName" 
                                 Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="uName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="pName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="brand" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="img" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="quantity" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="price" Type="Int64" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int64" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

for code behind file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    Response.Cookies["uname"].Value = s2;

}
```

finally the result i want is the total sum of cost of product display on a label control on the same page

Comment: It seems as if you want the sum of all instance of the field "price" here, but it's a little difficult to answer. What have you got working here, and what exactly, is it you need? Can you narrow your question down to some specific issue which would be easier to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking of that your cart.aspx page has a grid view for displaying the cart items and prices , then you can do like this....

you can do like this ... Simply in GridView.RowDataBound Event loop gridview and find control contain price amount and sum them

```
 decimal grdTotal = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {

      decimal rowTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "price"));

      grdTotal = grdTotal + rowTotal;
   }


   lbl.Text = grdTotal.ToString("c");

    }
 }
```

you can display total price value at the footer of price column .......

Comment: if i want to display the value of the grand total outside the gridview than what i have to do.

Comment: @prakashkumarjha see my edit try the above the row total will be displayed out side of the grid view...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the SqlDataSource control. Don't put SQL in aspx page! Create a class that returns cart and calculates grand total. Databind in code behind.

Comment: Why would you *not* use a `SQLDataSource` control?  Just curious, I have never heard of that as being bad practice or anything.

Comment: Because aspx is presentation not business logic. Because you repeat SQL on every page that needs it. When you make a change to a DB you have to change SQL in aspx. Because it makes simple tasks like displaying grand total hard. Solution provided calculates it in DataBound event. What if you don't use control with databound event? And if you do you put business logic in grid databound event!  Because it's not testable. I could find more reasons but I think it's enough.